# how directcast bindingsource datagridview databound List in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dapper, bindingsource, databound

after I delete in row datagridview then I update to database with "BTNUPDATE" but there is an error is there something wrong with my code.

if binding directly to datagridview without binding source then there is no error on "BTNUPDATE" but error on "BTNDELETE"

Thanks

Dear sir,

after I delete in row datagridview then I update to database with "BTNUPDATE" but there is an error is there something wrong with my code.

Thanks

```
 Dim pservice As New personService
    Private _source As New BindingSource()

    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _source.DataSource = pservice.GetPersondetail()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = _source
    End Sub

    Private Sub BTNDELETE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNDELETE.Click
        For Each dvr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
            If dvr IsNot Nothing Then
                DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dvr)
                DataGridView1.Refresh()
            End If
        Next dvr
    End Sub
    Private Sub BTNUPDATE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNUPDATE.Click
        Try
            If DataGridView1.RowCount = 0 Then
                Throw New Exception("no data")
            End If
            For Each item As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                Dim detail = DirectCast(item.DataBoundItem, persondetail)
                Dim GetStocks = New persondetail With {
                .Nameperson = detail.Nameperson,
                 .Age = detail.Age,
                  .Job = detail.Job,
                .ID = detail.ID,
                .Invono = detail.Invono}
                pservice.UpdatePersondetail(detail)
            Next item
            MessageBox.Show("successfully")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "myapp", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I want to be able to update with the "BTNUPDATE" event please recommend

Comment: What error and where EXACTLY?

Comment: Removing rows from the grid is useless. That doesn't do anything to the underlying data. Calling `Refresh` is also useless, as all that does is redraw the grid on screen. If you expect to delete data then you need to call the appropriate `Remove` method on the `BindingSource` to flag the underlying `DataRow` as `Deleted` and then use ADO.NET to delete that row(s).

Comment: @jmcilhinney ,`use ADO.NET to delete that row(s)`  `BTNUPDATE_Click` if I use it without binding source then I can update . if I use binding source an error occurs `object reference not set to an instance of an object` please guide from you

Comment: @jmcilhinney , if I use binding source so I can update in BTNUPDATE, is there any code that needs to be fixed?

Comment: @jmcilhinney ,  Thanks to your guidance I finally got a solution sorry if I replied to you too late. Is there anything from my answer that needs to be corrected

Answer (score 0):

as recommended by @jmcilhinney

```
 Dim pservice As New personService()
    Private _source As New BindingSource()
  Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _source.DataSource = pservice.GetPersondetail()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = _source
    End Sub
    Private Sub BTNDELETE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNDELETE.Click
  Try
            If MessageBox.Show("Delete selected record?", "CONFIRM!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) = DialogResult.Yes Then
             For Each dvr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
 Dim detail = DirectCast(dvr.DataBoundItem, persondetail)
  Dim persondetail = New persondetail With {
                    .ID = Convert.ToInt32(detail.ID),
                    .Invono = detail.Invono
                }
_source.remove(persondetail)
 pservice.DeletePersondetail(persondetail)
                    '' rebind!  
                    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
                    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = pservice.GetPersondetail()
                Next dvr
            End If
  Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "myapp", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
  
        End Try
    End Sub  Private Sub BTNUPDATE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNUPDATE.Click
        Try
            If DataGridView1.RowCount = 0 Then
                Throw New Exception("no data")
            End If
            For Each item As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                Dim detail = DirectCast(item.DataBoundItem, persondetail)
                Dim persondetail = New persondetail With {
                .Nameperson = detail.Nameperson,
                 .Age = detail.Age,
                  .Job = detail.Job,
                .ID = detail.ID,
                .Invono = detail.Invono}
 pservice.UpdatePersondetail(detail)
                '' rebind!  
                Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
                Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = pservice.GetPersondetail()
            Next item
            MessageBox.Show("successfully")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "myapp", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).